# isolate_namespace misses Rails::Engine::ActionDispatch when run in rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I am trying to write a module for an existing rails app (decidim), using TDD.
When I run the production code with rails runner, there is no problem:

```
decidim@elektori:~/elovalasztok$ rails runner lib/decidim/condorcet.rb 
decidim@elektori:~/elovalasztok$
```

When I run with rspec, there is missing dependency:

```
decidim@elektori:~/elovalasztok$ rspec 

An error occurred while loading ./spec/condorcet_spec.rb.
Failure/Error: isolate_namespace Decidim::Condorcet::Admin

NameError:
  uninitialized constant Rails::Engine::ActionDispatch
# ./lib/decidim/condorcet/admin_engine.rb:5:in `<class:AdminEngine>'
# ./lib/decidim/condorcet/admin_engine.rb:4:in `<module:Condorcet>'
# ./lib/decidim/condorcet/admin_engine.rb:3:in `<module:Decidim>'
# ./lib/decidim/condorcet/admin_engine.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
# ./lib/decidim/condorcet.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
# ./spec/condorcet_spec.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'


Finished in 0.00041 seconds (files took 1.39 seconds to load)
0 examples, 0 failures, 1 error occurred outside of examples

decidim@elektori:~/elovalasztok$
```

The first line of the spec file, which triggers the problem, is the following:

```
require 'decidim/condorcet'
```

Relevant files:

```
decidim@elektori:~/elovalasztok$ cat lib/decidim/condorcet.rb 
require "decidim/condorcet/admin"
require "decidim/condorcet/admin_engine"
module Decidim
  module Condorcet
      include ActiveSupport::Configurable
  end
end
decidim@elektori:~/elovalasztok$ cat lib/decidim/condorcet/admin_engine.rb 
require 'rails/engine'
module Decidim
    module Condorcet
        class AdminEngine < ::Rails::Engine
            isolate_namespace Decidim::Condorcet::Admin
        end
    end
end
```

I'm not even sure that the `require 'rails/engine'` line should be in condorcet.rb or some other place. And I could not figure out what to require to have `Rails::Engine::ActionDispatch` covered.

Where should I declare my dependencies, and what is the one for `Rails::Engine::ActionDispatch` ?

Answer (score 1):

So there is an rspec-rails gem: https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails
It basically takes care of the rails dependencies.
I did the following (already had the dependency in Gemfile):

```
rails generate rspec:install
```

to install needed files

added

```
require 'rails_helper'
```

to the spec file, and ran

```
bundle exec rspec
```